# Get image metadata from the image returned by the UIImagePickerController to find the geolocation?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to find the location of the photos that are taken using my iPhone camera, I need some help regarding fetching the location data from the metadata returned by UIImagePickerController??

I am using the latest version of iOS 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [Assets Library Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html) - this gives you access to metadata of pictures.  See `valueForProperty:` of the `ALAsset` class or the `metadata` property of the `ALAssetRepresentation` class.

**Edit**: Looks like you can get the metadata directly using the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` property that is returned in the `NSDictionary` from the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
```

(See the "[Editing Information Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys)")